# Empty values returned

Tags: java, arrays

Suppose you save $100 each month into a savings account with an annual interest rate of 5%. Thus, the monthly interest rate is 0.05/12 = 0.00417.

The code runs but I don't get any values back. I can't seem to get the code to work. It just returns 0.0 ??? I'm stuck.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class EmployeeSavings extends AddressBook {

    public static final double ANNUAL_INTEREST_RATE = 0.05;
    private double accountValue;
    public double[] monthlyInterests;
    public static double[] monthlySavings;

    public EmployeeSavings(String fn, String ln){
        setfirstName(fn);
        setlastName(ln);
    }


    public EmployeeSavings(String fn, String ln, double[] d1, double[] d2){
        setfirstName(fn);
        setlastName(ln);
        monthlySavings = d1;
        monthlyInterests = d2;

    }


    public static String getReport(EmployeeSavings[] arr) {
        for (EmployeeSavings arr1 : arr) {
            System.out.println("Employee Name: " + arr1.getfirstName() + " " + arr1.getlastName()
            + " " + "Account Value: " + arr1.getaccountValue());
        }
        return "Report was completed successfully";
    }

    public double getaccountValue() {
        for (int i = 0; i < monthlyInterests.length; i++) {
            accountValue = (accountValue + monthlyInterests[i] + monthlySavings[i]);
        }
        return accountValue;
    }

    public double[] calculateInterests() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        double[] savings = new double[12];
        for( int i = 0; i < savings.length; i++)
            savings[i] = (rand.nextDouble()*800 - 100) + 100;
        return monthlyInterests;
    }


    public double[] generateMonthlySavings() {
           Random rand = new Random();
           double[] savings = new double[12];
           double localUpperBound = 800 - 100d;
           for( int i = 0; i < savings.length; i++)
               savings[i] = (rand.nextDouble()*localUpperBound) + 100;
        return monthlySavings;
    }



    //Get methods
    public double[] getMonthlyInterests() {
        return monthlyInterests;
    }

    public double[] getMonthlySavings() {
         return monthlySavings;
    }



public static void main(String[] args) {

        EmployeeSavings [] employees = new EmployeeSavings[15];      

        double d1 [] = new double [12];
        double d2 [] = new double [12];

        employees[0] = new  EmployeeSavings("Elena", "Brandon", d1, d2);
        employees[1] = new  EmployeeSavings("Thomas", "Molson", d1, d2);
        employees[2] = new  EmployeeSavings("Hamilton", "Winn", d1, d2);
        employees[3] = new  EmployeeSavings("Suzie", "Sarandin", d1, d2);
        employees[4] = new  EmployeeSavings("Philip", "Winne", d1, d2);
        employees[5] = new  EmployeeSavings("Alex", "Trebok", d1, d2);
        employees[6] = new  EmployeeSavings("Emma", "Pivoto", d1, d2);
        employees[7] = new  EmployeeSavings("John", "Lenthen", d1, d2);
        employees[8] = new EmployeeSavings("James", "Lean", d1, d2);
        employees[9] = new EmployeeSavings("Jane", "Ostin", d1, d2);
        employees[10] = new EmployeeSavings("Emily", "Car", d1, d2);
        employees[11] = new EmployeeSavings("Daniel", "Hamshire", d1, d2);
        employees[12] = new EmployeeSavings("Neda", "Bazdar", d1, d2);
        employees[13] = new EmployeeSavings("Aaron", "Smith", d1, d2);
        employees[14] = new EmployeeSavings("Kate", "Hen", d1, d2);

        EmployeeSavings.getReport(employees);
```

Comment: Maybe you forgot to call `generateMonthlySavings`?

Comment: @cona please be more specific i.e. at what part of code you are facing issue. It will take a lot of time for people to go into your code, which should be avoided to get quick replies.

Here is what you should do:
1. Describe your code algo in pseudocode
2. Highlight the part where your issue exist - for this you should debug it yourself and then paste that part.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you call function `calculateInterests` and function `generateMonthlySavings`